# Why won't my prepared statement function properly?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an ajax call affiliated with the php handler that has a prepared statement in it.

And it won't work. No error is caught.

It just stopped working when I changed it from deprecated mysql_real_escape to pdo prepared statememt.

Here is my Code :

```
$create_pdo=new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
$statement=$create_pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (fname, lname, email, password, age, sex, city, timereg, frcode) VALUES (:fname_received, :lname_received, :email_received,  :password_received, :dob_received, :sex_received, :city_received, :timepassreg, :frcode)");
$statement->bindParam(':fname_received', $fname_received);
$statement->bindParam(':lname_received', $lname_received);
$statement->bindParam(':email_received', $email_received);
$statement->bindParam(':password_received', $password_received);
$statement->bindParam(':dob_received', $dob_received);
$statement->bindParam(':sex_received', $sex_received);
$statement->bindParam(':city_received', $city_received);
$statement->bindParam(':timepassreg', $timepassreg);
$statement->bindParam(':frcode', $frcode);
$statement_executed=$statement->execute();
if ($statement_executed){
$messagetosend="<font size=\"2\" color=\"#347C17\" face=\"Tahoma\"> <strong>Приветствуем нового пользователя проекта 'Фаворит'!</strong></font>,<br><font size=\"2\"        color=\"#1F2320\" face=\"Tahoma\">Для того, чтобы начать пользоваться нашим сайтом, вам нужно будет ввести авторизационный код.<br>Ваш авторизационный код: <font size=\"2\" color=\"#336699\" face=\"Tahoma\"><strong>".$frcode."</strong></font><br>Этот процесс проводится в целях борьбы со спамом и его предотвращения.<br>С уважением,<br>Проект 'Фаворит'.</font>";
$mailheader='MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
$mailheader.="X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";
$mailheader.="From: Фаворит <passwordreminder@favorit.kz>";
mail($email_received,"Авторизация на проекте 'Фаворит'",$messagetosend,$mailheader);
$array_to_json=array("database_input" => "true","mail_sent" => "true");
echo json_encode($array_to_json);
}
```

How can i fix this ?

Comment: See [Errors and error handling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php): by default, PDO handles errors silently (so, in the event that `$statement_executed` is false, one must inspect [`$statement->errorInfo()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php) to discover why); this can be changed so that PDO raises warnings or exceptions instead, according to one's preference.

Comment: I introduced a new variable $statement_error=$statement_executed->errorInfo();  As a result, I got Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$statement_error' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/letsrate/public_html/favorit/ajax/ajax_user_signup.php on line 41. SO the new variable caused the new error. The old error is still uncertain.

Comment: It should be `$statement->errorInfo()`, not `$statement_executed->errorInfo()`.

Comment: I got this error. Fatal error: Call to a member function errorInfo() on a non-object in /home/letsrate/public_html/favorit/ajax/ajax_user_signup.php on line 40

Comment: If `$statement` is a non-object, then the call to `$create_pdo->prepare()` must have failed (but then you should have received similar errors for the `bindParam()` and `execute()` calls?).  You can inspect `$create_pdo->errorInfo()` to discover why.

Comment: could that have happened because another prepared statement query was executed prior to that call?

Comment: PDOStatement Object( [queryString] => INSERT INTO REGISTRY (fname, lname, email, password, age, sex, city, timereg, frcode) VALUES (:fname_received, :lname_received, :email_received, :password_received, :dob_received, :sex_received, :city_received, :timepassreg, :frcode))

Comment: thats how that object is echoed

Comment: I don't understand.  `$statement` is a PDOStatement object, but when invoking `$statement->errorInfo()` you get "Call to a member function errorInfo() on a non-object"??

Comment: exactly. that is weird isn't it? also echoing the statement variable throughout binding all the parameters, it remains the same only containing the query with unchanged values with semicolumns sitting before them. is that the way its supposed to be?

Comment: I think you should [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22893586/edit) to show the code that exhibits the "Call to member function errorInfo() on a non-object" message.

Answer (score 0):

> And it won't work. No error is caught.

To display query errors, you need to set the error mode attribute to PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE. Then you will be able to see PDO errors the same way as other PHP errors

```
$create_pdo=new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
$create_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$statement=$create_pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO REGISTRY (fname, lname, email, password, age, sex, city, timereg, frcode) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
$statement_executed = $statement->execute(array($fname_received, $lname_received, $email_received, $password_received, $dob_received, $sex_received, $city_received, $timepassreg, $frcode));
```

Comment: Thanks, i didn't knew that! :>